# What’s the best way to cast a function pointer from one type to another?

Tags: c++, winapi, function-pointers, reinterpret-cast

I’ve searched Stack Overflow for an answer, but I get nothing specific to this problem: only general cases about use of various types of cast operators.
So, the case in point is when retrieving a function address with the Windows `GetProcAddress()` API call, which returns a function pointer of type `FARPROC`, with: `typedef INT_PTR (__stdcall *FARPROC)();`.

The trouble is, the actual function sought rarely (if ever) has this actual signature, as shown in the MRCE code, below. In this code, I have shown a variety of different attempts to convert the returned value to a function pointer of the appropriate type, with all but the fourth method commented out:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(__stdcall* TYPE_SetDPI)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT); // Function pointer typedef
static DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT __stdcall STUB_SetDpi(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT) { return nullptr; } // Dummy 'stub' function
static DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(__stdcall* REAL_SetDpi)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT) = STUB_SetDpi; // Func ptr to be assigned

using std::cout;    using std::endl;

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary("User32.dll");
    if (!hDll) {
        cout << "User32.dll failed to load!\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "User32.dll loaded succesfully..." << endl;

    // (1) Simple assignment doesn't work ...
//  REAL_SetDpi = GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");
    // (2) Using 'C'-style cast does work, but it is flagged as 'evil' ...
//  REAL_SetDpi = (TYPE_SetDPI)GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");
    // (3) Using reinterpret_cast: seems OK with clang-cl but MSVC doesn't like it ...
//  REAL_SetDpi = reinterpret_cast<TYPE_SetDPI>(GetProcAddress(hDll, 
    // (4) Using a temporary plain "void *": OK with MSVC but clang-cl complains ...
    void* tempPtr = GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");
    REAL_SetDpi = reinterpret_cast<TYPE_SetDPI>(tempPtr);
    // (5) Using a union (cheating? - but neither clang-cl nor MSVC give any warning!) ...
//  union {
//      intptr_t(__stdcall* gotProc)(void);
//      TYPE_SetDPI usrProc; // This has the 'signature' for the actual function.
//  } TwoProcs;
//  TwoProcs.gotProc = GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");
//  REAL_SetDpi = TwoProcs.usrProc;

    if (REAL_SetDpi == nullptr) cout << "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext function not found!" << endl;
    else                        cout << "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext function loaded OK!" << endl;

    FreeLibrary(hDll);
    return 0;
}
```

The various error/warning messages given by the `clang-cl` and native `MSVC` compiler, for each of the 5 options are as follows:

```
// (1) Simple assignment doesn't work ...
REAL_SetDpi = GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");

clang-cl -> error :  assigning to 'DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT (*)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT) __attribute__((stdcall))'
  (aka 'DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__ *(*)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__ *)') from incompatible type 'FARPROC' 
  (aka 'long long (*)()'): different number of parameters (1 vs 0)
Visual-C -> error C2440:  '=': cannot convert from 'FARPROC' to 
  'DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT (__cdecl *)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)'
  message :  This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
```

This error is (of course) expected, but the one confusing thing to me is why `MSVC` shows my function as `__cdecl` when I have explicitly declared it `__stdcall`?

```
// (2) Using 'C'-style cast does work, but it is flagged as dangerous ...
REAL_SetDpi = (TYPE_SetDPI)GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");

clang-cl -> warning :  use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
Visual-C -> warning C4191:  'type cast': unsafe conversion from 'FARPROC' to 'TYPE_SetDPI'
            warning C4191:   Calling this function through the result pointer may cause your program to fail
```

Generally, I endeavour to completely avoid old, ‘C’-style casts in my code! Where I am forced to do cast between ‘unrelated’ objects, I use explicit `reinterpret_cast` operators, as these are far easier to track down in code if problems arise. So, for case 3:

```
// (3) Using reinterpret_cast: seems OK with clang-cl but MSVC doesn't like it ...
REAL_SetDpi = reinterpret_cast<TYPE_SetDPI>(GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext"));

clang-cl -> No error, no warning!
Visual-C -> warning C4191:  'reinterpret_cast': unsafe conversion from 'FARPROC' to 'TYPE_SetDPI'
            Calling this function through the result pointer may cause your program to fail
```

Here, the `MSVC` warning is pretty much the same as for the C-style cast. Maybe I could live with this, but case 4 makes things more interesting:

```
// (4) Using a temporary plain "void *": OK with MSVC but clang-cl complains ...
void* tempPtr = GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");
REAL_SetDpi = reinterpret_cast<TYPE_SetDPI>(tempPtr);

clang-cl -> warning :  implicit conversion between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is a Microsoft extension
            [-Wmicrosoft-cast]
            warning :  cast between pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object is incompatible with C++98
            [-Wc++98-compat-pedantic]
```

Here, `MSVC` gives no warning – but I feel I’m simply ‘fooling’ the compiler! I can’t see how this can have any different overall effect than the code in case 3.

```
// (5) Using a union (cheating? - but neither clang-cl nor MSVC give any warning!) ...
union {
    intptr_t(__stdcall* gotProc)(void);
    TYPE_SetDPI usrProc; // This has the 'signature' for the actual function.
} TwoProcs;
TwoProcs.gotProc = GetProcAddress(hDll, "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext");
REAL_SetDpi = TwoProcs.usrProc;
```

I did post this as an answer (now retracted), to which @formerlyknownas_463035818 pointed out that this is *officially* Undefined Behaviour and/or disallowed in `C++` (the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning) given by the aforementioned commentator).

**Which option do I currently use?**

Well, as my software is specifically Windows-oriented, I use the last (option 4) for two reasons: (1) the `clang-cl` warning is the ‘least scary’; and (2) I like to think that `MSVC` is probably the best ‘mediator’ for compiling/building Windows apps.

> *EDIT: Since first posting this question, and having 'reviewed' the various comments and suggestions made, I have now changed **all
>   instances** of this type of cast (that is, from a function pointer
>   loaded via `GetProcAddress`) in my code to using the following
>   conversion 'function', defined in my global header file:*
>
> ```
> template<typename T> T static inline FprocPointer(intptr_t(__stdcall* inProc)(void)) {
>     __pragma(warning(suppress:4191)) // Note: no semicolon after this expression!
>     return reinterpret_cast<T>(inProc);
> }
> ```
>
> *This allows for easy/rapid location of any such casts, should I need (or wish) to change the way they work in future.*

**Why does it matter?**

Maybe it doesn’t! However, elsewhere in my code, I have come across an unexpected crash, when using function pointers loaded via `GetProcAddress()` - not any standard `WinAPI` calls, but functions from my own DLLs, loaded as plug-in modules. The code snippet below shows a potential case-in-point:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// These two routines are the 'interceptors' for plug-in commands; they check active plug-ins for handlers or updaters:

static int      plin;   //! NOTA BENE:  We use this in the two functions below, as the use of a local 'plin' loop index
                        //  is prone to induce stack corruption (?), especially in MSVC 2017 (MFC 14) builds for x86.

void BasicApp::OnUpdatePICmd(uint32_t nID, void *pUI)
{
//! for (int plin = 0; plin < Plugin_Number; ++plin) { // Can cause problems - vide supra
    for (plin = 0;  plin < Plugin_Number;  ++plin) {
        BOOL mEbl = FALSE;  int mChk = -1;
        if ((Plugin_UDCfnc[plin] != nullptr) && Plugin_UDCfnc[plin](nID, &mEbl, &mChk)) {
            CommandEnable(pUI, mEbl ? true : false);
            if (mChk >= 0) CmdUISetCheck(pUI, mChk);
            return;
        }
    }
    CommandEnable(pUI, false);
    return;
}

void BasicApp::OnPluginCmd(uint32_t nID)
{
//! for (int plin = 0; plin < Plugin_Number; ++plin) { // Can cause problems - vide supra
    for (plin = 0; plin < Plugin_Number; ++plin) {
        piHandleFnc Handler = nullptr;  void *pParam = nullptr;
        if ((Plugin_CHCfnc[plin] != nullptr) && Plugin_CHCfnc[plin](nID, &Handler, &pParam) && (Handler != nullptr)) {
            Handler(pParam);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Note that,  `Plugin_UDCfnc` and `Plugin_CHCfnc` are arrays of function pointers, loaded as described above.

**And, finally, what was my question, again?**

Two-fold:

1. Is it ‘safe’ to ignore the warnings?
2. Is there a better way, using the Standard Library (I’m still getting used to using this)
   – maybe something like `std::bind()`?

Any help, suggestions or recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT: I use the native `MSVC` compiler for my “Release” builds (with `/Wall`), and a few specific warnings explicitly disabled (locally) in code. From time to time, I run my entire code base through the `clang-cl` compiler, to look for other warnings of possible dodgy code (very useful, actually).*

Comment: i dont dare to write this as answer, but the best cast is definitely no cast

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 - But how can I ever use the loaded function without a cast, or some kind of conversion?

Comment: if anything I would cast the parameters and return type, and I would try to stay away from c-style casts or its cousin `reinterpret_cast` whenever possible

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 - OK, casting the return type is trivial, but how to cast my list of parameters, when the returned function has `(void)` parameters list?

Comment: I would use version 3 - it's the most common one, I believe - and (locally) disable the C4191 warning from VC++.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The function in the DLL doesn't actually have the `FARPROC` type (which is much like a `void*`, but for function pointers in this case). It must be cast to the appropriate type before you can use it, and you can only do that through reinterpret-casting or C-casting it.

Comment: Like the sample in the MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress   It's what others reading your code will expect to see.

Comment: @Richard Critten - However, that sample uses a (ugh) C-style cast! Changing to `reinterpret_cast` is the closest, I guess.

Comment: @molbdnilo thats why I wrote "whenever possible", I have to admit, I didnt fully understand OPs code, not familiar with Windows at all. If they force you to `reinterpret_cast` and this is common practice then of course I wont object

Comment: Why are you using two compilers? Do you need to enforce some kind of compatibility? If MSVC is your compiler, use (3) since it works with your tools.

Comment: you also can try use `*(void**)&SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext = GetProcAddress(...)` but not think this is something changed. and aslo exist very nice solution without any cast at all. but this already not language layer, but based on deep understand how CL work with [`__declspec( dllimport )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Adrian the WinAPI is a C API so C-style is appropriate.

Comment: @RbMm - Your answer does work, but `(void**)` is actually a C-style cast!

Comment: @Adrian - if want - can use `(void*&)SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext = GetProcAddress()` - i of course know better (from my look solution), but not sure if you will like it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Just to let you know I've deleted my own 'answer', on which you had made a valuable comment - now incorporated into edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think C/C++ are lacking a generic function pointer type, like `void*` as a generic object pointer type.

Generally, converting from one function pointer into another is supported, provided that you don't call the wrong function pointer type. See [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#reinterpret.cast-6):

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type.

A warning that is issued when casting one function pointer type to another is generally useful. Having such casting might cause a call to a function with the wrong signature. Such a problem might affect only a certain CPU architecture, or be noticed only with certain OS builds, so it might not be apparent after initial testing. The Standard just says *unspecified*, see [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#reinterpret.cast-6):

> Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

Whether `void*` can be converted to function pointer type and whether it even has enough bits is implementation specific. True for Windows, though. I wouldn't endorse Windows-specific habits for a generic problem. See
[[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#reinterpret.cast-8):

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported.

Type punning with unions raises an issue with strict aliasing ([What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)), so not a good way to outsmart a compiler.

**So, live with local warning suppression near your `GetProcAddress` calls, or in a `GetProcAddess` wrapper. Use `reinterpret_cast`.**

If you're going to use a helper function that casts one function type into another without a warning, be sure to use it only in `GetProcAddress`-like scenario, when you use some generic signature to temporary store function pointer, but that signature is not an actual signature -- not to call a function pointer by a not intended type.

Sorry.