# Using static_cast correctly in MFC

Tags: c++, static-cast

Changing this code was straightforward:

This:

```
S_COPY_PACKET* pCopyPacket = (S_COPY_PACKET*)(pCopyDataStruct->lpData);
```

Becomes:

```
S_COPY_PACKET* pCopyPacket = static_cast<S_COPY_PACKET*>(pCopyDataStruct->lpData);
```

But what about this line:

```
if (SendMessageTimeout(hOtherInstance, WM_COPYDATA,
                NULL, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds, SMTO_BLOCK, 2000, &dwResult) != 0)
```

We are passing in a `(LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds`. So what is the newer concept (inline with `static_cast`) for this?

Comment: what type is `cds`?

Comment: @bolov It is `COPYDATASTRUCT`.

Comment: My answer is wrong. the code with `static_cast` doesn't compile.

Comment: @bolov Oh, OK! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code snippet, the `lpData` member of the `COPYDATASTRUCT` is a `void*` type, so you can `static_cast` it to a pointer to (almost) any other data type. However, you cannot use `static_cast` to convert between a pointer (`&cds`) and non-pointer (`LPARAM`) type. You need `reinterpret_cast` (but only one):

```cpp
if (SendMessageTimeout(hOtherInstance, WM_COPYDATA,
                NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&cds), SMTO_BLOCK, 2000, &dwResult) != 0)
```

Although such casts are frequently frowned-upon by 'purist' C++ programmers, there is really no other way to avoid them, other than the even nastier 'C-style' cast(s) that your 'old' code already has. This derives from the fact that the WinAPI was written as a C interface, so its use in more modern, C++ code will inevitably have some such 'inconsistencies'.

*(The problem becomes even trickier when using WinAPI calls that involve function pointers, as I pondered here: [What’s the best way to cast a function pointer from one type to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57973305/10871073).)*

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&<something>)` will be found frequently in WinAPI calls that involve Windows messages, where the `lParam` argument is (of necessity) a pointer to something.