# static_cast from 'FARPROC' is not allowed

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get rid of a warning in my code, but I'm in way over my head here...

The original code row looks like this:

```
FeasaCom_Open=(tFeasaCom_Open)(GetProcAddress(static_cast<HMODULE>(hFeasaComDLL), "FeasaCom_Open"));
```

The warning that's thrown is:

> warning: use of old-style cast

I've tried to fix this by re-writing it in this way:

```
FeasaCom_Open=static_cast<tFeasaCom_Open>(GetProcAddress(static_cast<HMODULE>(hFeasaComDLL), "FeasaCom_Open"));
```

But then I get the warning:

> error: static_cast from 'FARPROC' (aka 'int (*)() __attribute__((stdcall))') to 'tFeasaCom_Open' (aka 'int (*)(int, char *) __attribute__((stdcall))') is not allowed

The definition of FeasaCom_Open is:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *tFeasaCom_Open)(int CommPort, char * Baudrate);
```

And declaration is:

```
tFeasaCom_Open FeasaCom_Open;
```

I probably don't need to tell you this, but declaration of `GetProcAddress` looks like this:

```
WINBASEAPI FARPROC WINAPI GetProcAddress (HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName);
```

And FARPROC:

```
typedef int (WINAPI *FARPROC) ();
```

I've tried to fix this, but I don't really know what I'm doing here... I'm using Qt 5.9.6 with MinGW 5.3.0 32-bit, if that's any help.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57973305/10871073) from me! Although there is no formal answer there, you may find some of the discussion helpful.

Comment: you need to `reinterpret_cast` not `static_cast`

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, why do you have to cast `hFeasaComDLL`? Why is it not an `HMODULE` already? After all, that's what `LoadLibrary` and friends return. Also, you should probably not be using the 32-bit version of MinGW. It hasn't been updated in ages, and ships with rather incomplete Windows support. Go with the 64-bit version, if you must use MinGW.

Comment: @IInspectable Really sorry for not answering sooner! I have no idea why it's done this way. I'm using a code example from Feasa written in C for a LED Analyzer. https://www.feasa.ie/ledanalyser.html
It was fairly easy to get the code example to work in C++ (Qt 5), but there was quite a few warnings to solve. Now they are all gone and the code works, that's all I need. :) 

I will update MinGW next time I release this software. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @AlanBirtles Then you will get: Don't use reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @huang not sure why you're dredging up a 4 year old question but if you need `reinterpret_cast` then it's the right tool. Yes you should avoid needing to use it but in this case `GetProcAddress` doesn't return typed function pointers so you have to use a c style or `reinterpret_cast` to change to the correct type